# supress PATH in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file:

```
set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin\;%PATH%@
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe c:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\newbatch.sh
```

that outputs:

> C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop>set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
>   C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK
>   \2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\
>   Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Prog
>   ram Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\@

C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop>c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe c:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\newbatch.
sh

MENU

```
==================================


     1  Match patient

     2  Sanger analysis

     3  Batch analysis

     4  Individual analysis

     5  Supplemental analysis

     6  Exit


==================================

     Your choice:
```

How can I suppress the full path from showing (all the text before MENU)?  Thank you.

Comment: prefix `set` with @, meaning "do not echo this command"

Comment: or write `@echo off` as first line in your batchfile, which means "do not echo any command from now on"

Comment: I used @echo off as set@ is not a recognizable command, I probably misunderstood.  Thank you both :).